# "concurrently" lexing and parsing vs lexing then parsing?

Tags: parsing, lexical-analysis

I've seen a few languages that will eat a token, then parse the token and then when they need to check the next token whilst parsing, they request it from the lexer.

So you have `if (x == 3)` you lex, check what it is in this case an if, lex again and make sure its a (, parse an expression which requests 3 in this case till it finishes parsing an expression, and then you lex and expect a closing parenthesis.

The other alternative is you lex this input stream as `keyword, symbol, identifier, equality, number, symbol` and then you give that token list to the parser which will parse it into an AST.

What are the pros/cons of these two techniques?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For most grammars, it doesn't really matter whether you lex the entire input into a token list as a first pass, then take tokens from the list during a parse pass, or lex on demand. The second method avoids the need for an in-memory token list, the first method means that you can parse several times a bit faster, which you might want to do in an interpreter.

However if the grammar require more than one token of lookahead or isn't left-right then you might need to lex more. Whilst natural languages have some odd parse rules ("time flies like an arrow, fruit flies like bananas"), computer languages are usually designed to be parseable with a simple recursive descent parser with one token of lookahead.

Comment: Two notable examples to "usually parseably designed" are C (potentially unbound lookahead) and C++ (parsers are Turing-complete).